# Error while trying to install wine-stable 5.0.0

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

I'm new in the community.
I have a problem while installing wine, it says:

> ```
> "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~bionic)
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."
> ```

I tried with aptitude to install all other packages that may be broken, but I don't know what to do now. My Gnome version is 3.28.2, I use Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) .
If need more details are needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried install wine from synaptic? the version that is there is the 3.0.1, but it would serve to you in the most of the cases.

You should look for wine stable there, and then install it. The dependencies will install with it.

If for some reason you need a newer version, try doing this:

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: All this is right, but https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu do not have fully reproducible instruction for installation on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. [Shame on Wine developers](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48513).